# Image dropdown list in modal popup mvc

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I need a icon `drop-down` list to be displayed in modal popup in a **MVC** application. User selects the image and hits OK `button` on the modal popup and this data gets saved to database. Is there any control to do the same? Can we achieve this using `htmldropdownlistfor`?

Please advice!

Comment: How to display image icons in a dropdown list in mvc? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to create `dialog`/`modal`.

[**API Documentation**](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Place your `select` drop-down in your dialog & `submit` through a `form` or `ajax`.